# C# IF Else loop

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to create a c# program that will look in a folder for files. If the files are found then I want to start a program. If the file is not there then I want to program to sleep for 30 minutes and look in the folder again. I want to keep doing it maybe 10 times and if it still doesn’t find the file then exit the program. I wrote the `if` part but I need help on the `else` part. This is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Diagnostics;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // See if this file exists in the SAME DIRECTORY.
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\name.txt"))
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\bulkload.bat");
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  Post the relevant code so we know where to start.

Comment: Link at least the code and explain what doesn't work

Comment: Use `Thread.Sleep(int)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx

Comment: Wow - closing a fairly legitimate (albeit incomplete) question in less than 3 minutes from a new user after two suggested changes?

Comment: Yep, exactly what I thought. The question in itself is pretty readable and sort of like pseudocode

Comment: I would vote to re-open this question if I had such privileges.  The question may be basic but I would certainly say it is a "Real Question".  Give the guy a chance.

Comment: If you want to check multiple times, use a `for` or `while` loop. As for the sleep part, did you try [searching first](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+sleep)?

Comment: Consider using the FileSystemWatcher class to watch for changes in the file system. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Untested, for guidance purpose only.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\name.txt"))
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\bulkload.bat");
        return;
    }
    else //no need of else block really.
    {
        Thread.Sleep(30 * 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't Thread.Sleep() going to freeze his program for 30 minutes?

Comment: @jszigeti its only intended for guiding him. May be his app requires only that (gui-less app?).